# method name not recognized when using subscribe in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have the following code block, I am not sure why the checkValidUser() method is not being recognized within the subscribe block as well as out the subscribe method. The typescript error I am getting is "ts] Cannot find name 'checkValidUser'." Can someone let me know what the issue could be?

```
this.svsOrders.newOrderDetails(customerInfo).subscribe(
      (data:any)=>checkValidUser(),
      error=>this.errorMessage=<any>error
        )
      checkValidUser():void(){
        //IF-ELSE CODE BLOCK ONE
              if (data == 'Invalid User') {       
               this.isValidUser=false;
               let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                 title: 'Submit Order',
                 message: 'Access Denied',
                 buttons: [
                   {
                     text: 'Ok',
                     role: 'cancel',
                     handler: () => {
                       console.log('Cancel clicked');

                     }
                   }],
                 enableBackdropDismiss: false
               });
               alert.present();       
             } //close if
             else {   
               this.svsSummary.newOrderInfo(data);       
             } //close else

               //IF-ELSE CODE BLOACK TWO
               if(this.isValidUser){
                   console.log('isValidUser value(TRUE)', this.isValidUser)  
                   this.navCtrl.setRoot(CategoryPage);
                   this.navCtrl.popToRoot;
                   this.svsSummary.clearItemList();
                   return
               } else { 
                 console.log('popping the page now.....')
                 this.navCtrl.pop();
               }
       }
```

Thank you,
aj

Comment: This syntax looks incorrect to me. Is `checkValidUser` a class method? If so, try `this. checkValidUser()` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line no 2, should be `this.checkValidUser()`?